# Microsoft Outlook 2013 with Windows 8 layout

Tags: css, email, outlook-2013

I got a email. My table seems to have some margin even if I specified margin : 0; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;. i've also tried to add some !important on it but nothing happened. Everything is fine on other email viewer.

Got ideas?

[image: layout problem on Outlook 2013 for Windows 8 only]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title></head><body style="text-align:center;background-color:#b8b8b8;"><div></div><div></div><div style="text-align:center;background-color:#b8b8b8;"><table width="723" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;padding-bottom:0px;background-color:#ffffff;margin:0px auto;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;padding-top:0px;"><tr><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;"><tr><td style="WIDTH: 16px; HEIGHT: 33px;background-color:#b8b8b8;"></td><td style="WIDTH: 66px"></td><td width="315"></td><td width="286"></td><td width="2" style="background-color:#b8b8b8;"></td></tr><tr><td style="WIDTH: 16px; HEIGHT: 158px;background-color:#b8b8b8;"></td><td style="WIDTH: 66px"></td><td align="left" valign="top" style="WIDTH: 315px;font-size:0px;">&nbsp;<a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/64f8b3e6-3642-4534-a22c-f538a7cca052/tracker.jpg"><img src="cid:logo.jpg"></a></td><td width="288" valign="top"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;"><tr><td width="28" height="95"></td><td align="left" valign="middle" style="WIDTH: 260px"><span><table style="WIDTH: 100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td align="left" valign="top" style="WIDTH: 10px;background:#e59f01;" rowspan="2"></td><td align="left" valign="top" style="WIDTH: 12px" rowspan="2"></td><td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-bottom:10px;"><img src="cid:infolettre-titre.png"></td></tr><tr><td align="left" valign="top" rowspan="2" colspan="2" style="font-size:14px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:black;text-transform:uppercase;">Juillet <span style="color:#e59f03;">2013</span></td></tr></table></span></td></tr><tr><td width="28" height="28" style="background-color:#171a1b;"></td><td align="left" style="background-color:#171a1b;font-size:0px;"><img src="cid:derniere-heure.png"></td></tr><tr><td width="28" height="35" style="background-color:#171a1b;"></td><td width="260" align="left" valign="top" style="background-color:#171a1b;"><span style="line-height:normal;text-transform:uppercase !important;color:#f1b700 !important;font-size:11px !important;text-transform:uppercase;color:#f1b700;font-size:11px;">Augmentation de la <br>notoriété nmédienne</span></td></tr></table></td><td width="2" style="background-color:#b8b8b8;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" valign="top" style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;"><tr><td width="2" height="95"></td></tr><tr><td width="2" height="63" style="background-color:#171a1b;">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="WIDTH: 433px;background-color:#ffffff;font-size:0px;"><table style="WIDTH: 433px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td width="16" style="WIDTH: 16px;background-color:#b8b8b8;"><img src="cid:spacer.gif" width="16" height="180" style=""></td><td width="417" style="background-color:#ffffff;"></td></tr></table></td><td align="center" valign="top" style="WIDTH: 290px;background-color:#ffffff;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;background-color:#ffffff;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;"><tr><td style="WIDTH: 10px; HEIGHT: 138px;background-color:#171a1b;font-size:0px;"><img src="cid:shadow.png" width="10" height="138" style=""></td><td width="18" style="background-color:#171a1b;"><img src="cid:spacer.gif" width="19" height="10" style=""></td><td align="left" valign="top" style="WIDTH: 221px;background-color:#171a1b;"><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/274b3bfc-9625-4d72-98fe-f4d3eadc940c/tracker.jpg"><img src="cid:googlemapperso.jpg" style="border-bottom:#9a9a9a 1px solid;border-left:#9a9a9a 1px solid;padding-bottom:4px;background-color:white;padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px;border-top:#9a9a9a 1px solid;border-right:#9a9a9a 1px solid;padding-top:4px;border:#9a9a9a 1px solid;border:#9a9a9a 1px solid !important;"></a></td><td style="WIDTH: 39px;background-color:#171a1b;"><img src="cid:spacer.gif" width="39" height="10" style=""></td><td width="2" style="background-color:#171a1b;"></td></tr><tr><td width="10" height="99" valign="top" style="background-color:#171a1b;font-size:0px;"><img src="cid:shadow.png" width="10" height="149" style=""></td><td width="18" style="background-color:#171a1b;">&nbsp;</td><td width="221" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height:normal;background-color:#171a1b;color:white;font-size:11px;">Récemment, Nmédia a lancé son projet Google Street View. Celui-ci s’est avéré innovateur et original, mais en plus, il a fait en sorte que sa notoriété se développe à l’international, surtout dans la blogosphère aux États-Unis.</td><td style="WIDTH: 39px;background-color:#171a1b;"></td><td style="WIDTH: 2px;background-color:#171a1b;"></td></tr><tr><td style="HEIGHT: 27px;background-color:#171a1b;font-size:0px;"><img src="cid:shadow.png" width="10" height="27" style=""></td><td style="background-color:#171a1b;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="background-color:#171a1b;"><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/274b3bfc-9625-4d72-98fe-f4d3eadc940c/tracker.jpg"><img src="cid:lire-article.png"></a></td><td style="background-color:#171a1b;"></td><td style="background-color:#171a1b;"></td></tr><tr><td style="HEIGHT: 51px;background-color:#ffffff;"></td><td style="background-color:#ffffff;"></td><td style="background-color:#ffffff;font-size:0px;"><img src="cid:nquotidien.png"></td><td style="background-color:#f1ac00;"></td><td style="background-color:#f1ac00;"></td></tr><tr><td style="background-color:#ffffff;"></td><td style="background-color:#f1f0f0;"></td><td align="left" valign="top" style="background-color:#f1f0f0;"><div style="display:inline-block;"><div><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#000000;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;"><tr><td width="180" height="20">&nbsp;</td><td width="41">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td align="left"><span><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/18e711d1-8a2c-4b27-9a26-1efcd388f63c/tracker.jpg"><img src="cid:mbdc.jpg" style="border-bottom:#9a9a9a 1px solid;border-left:#9a9a9a 1px solid;padding-bottom:4px;background-color:white;padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px;border-top:#9a9a9a 1px solid;border-right:#9a9a9a 1px solid;padding-top:4px;border:#9a9a9a 1px solid;border:#9a9a9a 1px solid !important;"></a></span><h3 style="color:#222222 !important;font-size:12px !important;text-decoration:none !important;color:#222222;font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;"><span><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/18e711d1-8a2c-4b27-9a26-1efcd388f63c/tracker.jpg" style="color:#222222 !important;font-size:12px !important;text-decoration:none !important;color:#222222;font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;">Nmédia officiellement certifiée Google AdWords Partner!</a></span></h3><p style="margin-bottom:6px;font-size:11px !important;font-size:11px;"><span>Pour une entreprise comme Nmédia, la notoriété dans Google est très intéressante. C’est pourquoi l’entreprise est fière d’avoir des employés certifiés Google AdWords.</span></p></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#000000;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;"><tr><td width="209" align="right"><span><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/18e711d1-8a2c-4b27-9a26-1efcd388f63c/tracker.jpg"><img src="cid:fleche_grise.png"></a></span></td><td width="12">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></div></div><div style="display:inline-block;"><div><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#000000;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;"><tr><td width="180" height="20">&nbsp;</td><td width="41">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td align="left"><span><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/c233dd7c-8eb7-4376-b96f-b1d219ce7051/tracker.jpg"><img src="cid:viruslan.jpg" style="border-bottom:#9a9a9a 1px solid;border-left:#9a9a9a 1px solid;padding-bottom:4px;background-color:white;padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px;border-top:#9a9a9a 1px solid;border-right:#9a9a9a 1px solid;padding-top:4px;border:#9a9a9a 1px solid;border:#9a9a9a 1px solid !important;"></a></span><h3 style="color:#222222 !important;font-size:12px !important;text-decoration:none !important;color:#222222;font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;"><span><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/c233dd7c-8eb7-4376-b96f-b1d219ce7051/tracker.jpg" style="color:#222222 !important;font-size:12px !important;text-decoration:none !important;color:#222222;font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;">Des entreprises sous le «&nbsp;choc&nbsp;»!</a></span></h3><p style="margin-bottom:6px;font-size:11px !important;font-size:11px;"><span>Le Choc des entreprises de fut pas de tout repos pour Nmédia. La Nmédienne Roxane Cotnoir a été déclarée vainqueure lors de cette activité.</span></p></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#000000;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;"><tr><td width="209" align="right"><span><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/c233dd7c-8eb7-4376-b96f-b1d219ce7051/tracker.jpg"><img src="cid:fleche_grise.png"></a></span></td><td width="12">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></div></div><div style="display:inline-block;"><div><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#000000;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;"><tr><td width="180" height="20">&nbsp;</td><td width="41">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td align="left"><span><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/d6b038a6-6510-42ea-8cfa-c360c3dd0984/tracker.jpg"><img src="cid:classiquegolf.jpg" style="border-bottom:#9a9a9a 1px solid;border-left:#9a9a9a 1px solid;padding-bottom:4px;background-color:white;padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px;border-top:#9a9a9a 1px solid;border-right:#9a9a9a 1px solid;padding-top:4px;border:#9a9a9a 1px solid;border:#9a9a9a 1px solid !important;"></a></span><h3 style="color:#222222 !important;font-size:12px !important;text-decoration:none !important;color:#222222;font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;"><span><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/d6b038a6-6510-42ea-8cfa-c360c3dd0984/tracker.jpg" style="color:#222222 !important;font-size:12px !important;text-decoration:none !important;color:#222222;font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;">Nmédia Solutions encourage encore une fois les étudiants travaillants</a></span></h3><p style="margin-bottom:6px;font-size:11px !important;font-size:11px;"><span>Lors du Gala des réussites du Cégep de Matane, Nmédia a donné une bourse de 500 $ à l’équipe «&nbsp;Café’t-vous?&nbsp;» composée de finissants en Techniques d’intégration multimédia.</span></p></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#000000;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;"><tr><td width="209" align="right"><span><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/d6b038a6-6510-42ea-8cfa-c360c3dd0984/tracker.jpg"><img src="cid:fleche_grise.png"></a></span></td><td width="12">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></div></div><div style="display:inline-block;"><div><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#000000;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;"><tr><td width="180" height="20">&nbsp;</td><td width="41">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td align="left"><span><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/dd5ce872-5274-4eb3-ad05-06587727cb4f/tracker.jpg"><img src="cid:reseauxsociaux.jpg" style="border-bottom:#9a9a9a 1px solid;border-left:#9a9a9a 1px solid;padding-bottom:4px;background-color:white;padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px;border-top:#9a9a9a 1px solid;border-right:#9a9a9a 1px solid;padding-top:4px;border:#9a9a9a 1px solid;border:#9a9a9a 1px solid !important;"></a></span><h3 style="color:#222222 !important;font-size:12px !important;text-decoration:none !important;color:#222222;font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;"><span><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/dd5ce872-5274-4eb3-ad05-06587727cb4f/tracker.jpg" style="color:#222222 !important;font-size:12px !important;text-decoration:none !important;color:#222222;font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;">Les Nmédiens ont été au rendez-vous à la course « des Chênes-toi! »</a></span></h3><p style="margin-bottom:6px;font-size:11px !important;font-size:11px;"><span>Dans le cadre de la course <br>«&nbsp;des Chênes-toi!» organisée par la Commission scolaire des Chênes, les Nmédiens sont allés relever le défi lancé aux entreprises de la région qui consistait à courir une distance de 5&nbsp;km.</span></p></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#000000;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;"><tr><td width="209" align="right"><span><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/dd5ce872-5274-4eb3-ad05-06587727cb4f/tracker.jpg"><img src="cid:fleche_grise.png"></a></span></td><td width="12">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></div></div></td><td valign="top" style="background-color:#ffffff;font-size:0px;"><img src="cid:corner3.png"></td><td valign="top" style="background-color:#ffffff;font-size:0px;"><img src="cid:corner4.png"></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;"><tr><td width="15" style="background-color:#b8b8b8;"></td><td width="71" style="background-color:#171a1b;"></td><td width="586" align="left" style="background-color:#171a1b;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;"><tr><td width="369" align="left" valign="bottom" style="WIDTH: 369px; HEIGHT: 49px"><img src="cid:ce-qui-fait-jaser.png"></td><td style="WIDTH: 40px"><img src="cid:spacer.gif" width="40" height="49" style=""></td><td width="177" align="left" valign="bottom" style="WIDTH: 177px"><img src="cid:le-conseil-du-mois.png"></td></tr><tr><td align="left" valign="top"><div style="display:inline-block;"><div><h3 style="margin-bottom:10px;color:#b6b6b7 !important;font-size:14px !important;text-decoration:none !important;color:#b6b6b7;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;"><span><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/03385860-7d1a-4f3b-8307-8be75a3e107e/tracker.jpg" style="color:#b6b6b7 !important;font-size:14px !important;text-decoration:none !important;color:#b6b6b7;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;text-decoration:none !important;">Chris Hadfield : la vedette médiatique</a></span></h3><p style="margin-top:8px;margin-bottom:16px;color:#ffffff !important;font-size:11px !important;color:#ffffff;font-size:11px;margin-top:8px;margin-bottom:16px;color:#ffffff !important;font-size:11px !important;color:#ffffff;font-size:11px;"><span style="margin-top:8px;margin-bottom:16px;color:#ffffff !important;font-size:11px !important;color:#ffffff;font-size:11px;">&nbsp;<span style="margin-top:8px;margin-bottom:16px;color:#ffffff !important;font-size:11px !important;color:#ffffff;font-size:11px;">L’astronaute Chris Hadfield est revenu sur la planète Terre. S’il a effectué une belle mission, lui et son équipe ont aussi développé une excellente stratégie pour que les gens s’intéressent au programme spatial. Au départ, Chris Hadfield comptait 22 000 personnes qui le suivaient sur Twitter.<br><br>Ce nombre s’élève à plus de 840 000 aujourd’hui. C’est d’abord et avant tout une stratégie proactive qui a été utilisée. Les interventions de Chris Hadfield ont été choisies et scénarisées bien à l’avance. Les médias sociaux ont permis de montrer ce qu’est la vie dans l’espace, comment fonctionne la station internationale et ce que sont les activités scientifiques du Canada. </span></span></p></div></div></td><td></td><td align="left" valign="top"><div style="display:inline-block;"><div><h3 style="margin-bottom:10px;color:#b6b6b7 !important;font-size:14px !important;text-decoration:none !important;color:#b6b6b7;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;"><span><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/47ce6467-1e8a-4854-9b5f-cf4187a7f251/tracker.jpg" style="color:#b6b6b7 !important;font-size:14px !important;text-decoration:none !important;color:#b6b6b7;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;text-decoration:none !important;">Procurez-vous un système pour sécuriser les mots de&nbsp;passe</a></span></h3><p style="margin-top:8px;margin-bottom:16px;color:#ffffff !important;font-size:11px !important;color:#ffffff;font-size:11px;margin-top:8px;margin-bottom:16px;color:#ffffff !important;font-size:11px !important;color:#ffffff;font-size:11px;"><span style="margin-top:8px;margin-bottom:16px;color:#ffffff !important;font-size:11px !important;color:#ffffff;font-size:11px;"><p style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;color:#ffffff !important;font-size:11px !important;color:#ffffff;font-size:11px;margin-top:8px;margin-bottom:16px;color:#ffffff !important;font-size:11px !important;color:#ffffff;font-size:11px;">Vous avez tendance à oublier vos mots de passe? Ces derniers sont trop faciles à être piratés? Procurez-vous un système pour sécuriser vos mots de passe. Keepass est un petit logiciel gratuit qui va assembler tous vos mots de passe dans une seule et même base de données.</p><p style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;color:#ffffff !important;font-size:11px !important;color:#ffffff;font-size:11px;margin-top:8px;margin-bottom:16px;color:#ffffff !important;font-size:11px !important;color:#ffffff;font-size:11px;"></p></span></p></div></div></td></tr><tr><td height="30" align="right" valign="top"><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/03385860-7d1a-4f3b-8307-8be75a3e107e/tracker.jpg"><img src="cid:fleche_noir.png"></a></td><td></td><td align="right" valign="top"><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/47ce6467-1e8a-4854-9b5f-cf4187a7f251/tracker.jpg"><img src="cid:fleche_noir.png"></a></td></tr></table><table width="477" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:#171a1b 2px solid;border-left:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;border-top:#ebebeb 2px solid;border-right:0px;"><tr><td width="240" height="65" align="left" valign="middle"><img src="cid:restons-connectes.png"></td><td width="50" height="65" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/75e9465e-7774-432c-91dd-fa0a0d7b2c55/tracker.jpg"><img src="cid:twitter.png"></a></td><td width="50" height="65" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/6414c05c-d6da-4276-9569-0e7c118b0ee2/tracker.jpg"><img src="cid:facebook.png"></a></td><td width="50" height="65" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/b89b99cd-f421-4f37-8dbf-82d37b3f65d7/tracker.jpg"><img src="cid:linkin.png"></a></td><td align="left" width="87" height="65" valign="middle">&nbsp;<a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/7079f8c1-2944-462f-b6ec-3f2f41f5cec3/tracker.jpg"><img src="cid:google_plusInfolettre.png"></a></td><td width="87" height="65" align="left" valign="middle"></td></tr></table></td><td width="51" style="background-color:#171a1b;"></td></tr></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;"><tr><td width="16" height="35" style="background-color:#b8b8b8;"></td><td width="69" style="background-color:#ffffff;"></td><td width="506" align="left" valign="middle" style="background-color:#ffffff;font-size:11px;">© Nmédia Solutions Inc. - <a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/5c1132f3-0ee1-4fe1-b3f9-ed30b8c98bc2/tracker.jpg" style="color:#464646;color:#464646;color:#464646 !important;">Notes Légales</a></td><td align="left" valign="middle" style="WIDTH: 132px;background-color:#ffffff;font-size:11px;"><a href="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/c2ea4bb5-6811-44d3-8987-fe1204e0b13c/tracker.jpg" style="color:#464646;">Désabonnement</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div><img src="" style="position:absolute;left:-10px;top:-10px;width:1px;height:1px;"><img src="http://www/MailTracker/8ea7f317-4eb1-4e42-91d7-1c14d326a251/12236/1e5b6f0d-615b-4431-8696-fd747b478943/tracker.jpg" style="width:1px;height:1px"></body></html>
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 1):

Your main table has uneven numbers of table cells in it. Every row needs to add up to the same, unless you are using colspans. Your table cell with a width of 288, needs colspan="2" as it spans the above cells that are 286 and 2 pixels respectively.

You should also always declare the widths consistently in html `width=""`, the first couple of table cells in the first row use css instead, which may be causing problems.

Once you fix those things, repost your code. There are too many things to pinpoint any exact issue at the moment.